# UI-Router: Height:100% on body element ignoring nested view height

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router, sticky-footer

I'm building an angular application that frequently uses nested views. Certain views, however, are taller than the other elements on the page and end up extending well beyond the end of the parent view.

I'm using [Ryan Fait's Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) so I have a wrapper around a containing div set to `height:100%` and I would have expected the page to just adapt and move the footer to the bottom of the nested view however I'm seeing the style elements of the footer `border` and `background-color` are remaining at end of the parent div while the content of the footer is being pushed to the end of the nested div.

Including an image as I'm struggling with getting the language exact:
[image]

I'm really looking for any solution from fixing the css to something that seems hackier like changing the footer or using ng-if/ng-class on certain pages. I'm imagining I'm misunderstanding something about CSS/UI-Router but I can't really track it.

The code isn't really interesting but here is it?

**CODE**

```css
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}
.push {
  height: 50px;
}
.footer {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
}
.nested {
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>
      <h1>Some text</h1>
      <ui-view class="nested"></ui-view>
    </div>
    <div class="push"></div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <span>some copy</span>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: create a demo that reproduces this. CSS `flexbox` would cure all this

Comment: This is purely a CSS problem (resp. understanding certain aspects thereof), and has nothing to do with angular in particular. It's what setting a fixed height _does_. The height of your wrapper is not limited, because you only set a min-height - but the height of body is limited, so content that extends more than that height is allowed to flow out of the body element, but doesn't _extend_ its height. Go look into the viewport-related units, specifically `vh` - and use those for your (min-)heights. They don't need a fixed height on the parent element to work, unlike heights in percentage.

Comment: Apologies @CBroe but I'm not sure I'm following your suggestion. Are you saying to apply a min-height viewport unit on <body> as that's something I've tried and hasn't worked... or am I misreading your suggestion entirely.

Comment: Not only for body, but for your wrapper as well (if you want that to extend higher than small content as well.) And no heights. // Flexbox makes this easier, so unless you need to satisfy onld devices that don't support it, I would suggest going that way.

Comment: Okay flexbox does make this much easier. Thanks to both of you. If either of you care about the credit for the answer just toss one up and happy to mark it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use percentage values for height (i.e. a relative height), the parent element heights have to be defined too. In your case you also need `height: 100%` on body and html, like

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```